# Getting Stackoverflow exception when executing LINQ IQueryable method

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

When running this code it's getting stackoverflow exception like this

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll

```
    private IQueryable<KontratMasraflari> SKontratMasraflari()
    {
        var _kontratlar = SKontrat().ToList();//IQueryable Method
        List<KontratMasraflari> _tumMasraflar = new List<KontratMasraflari>();
        foreach (var kontrat in _kontratlar)
        {
            var _masraf = db.KontratMasraflaris.Where(x => x.KontratID == kontrat.ID).SingleOrDefault();
            if (_masraf == null)
                _tumMasraflar.Add(new KontratMasraflari()
                {
                    KontratID = kontrat.ID
                });
            else
                _tumMasraflar.Add(_masraf);
        } 
        var _result = PredicateBuilder.True<KontratMasraflari>();
        _result = _result.And(x => x.Silindi == 0);

        if (txtFirmaTuru.Text != string.Empty)
            _result = _result.And(x => x.FirmaTuru == txtFirmaTuru.Text);
        if (txtBelgeNo.Text != string.Empty)
            _result = _result.And(x => x.BelgeNumarasi == txtBelgeNo.Text);
        if (txtMasraf.Text != string.Empty)
            _result = _result.And(x => x.Masraf == txtMasraf.Text);
        if (txtGelirGider.Text != string.Empty)
            _result = _result.And(x => x.GelirGider == txtGelirGider.Text);

        //var _return = db.KontratMasraflaris.Where(_result); 
        return _tumMasraflar.AsQueryable().Where(_result);;
    }
```

Comment: Can you get information about the stack?  Is this method being invoked in some kind of recursive chain?

Comment: i am calling in find method
` var result2 = from k in SKontrat().DefaultIfEmpty() 
                                  from m in SKontratMasraflari().DefaultIfEmpty().GroupBy(x => x.KontratID) 
                                  where 
                                      m.FirstOrDefault().KontratID == k.ID`

Comment: on the last line, do you really need to add AsQueryable() on _tumMasraflar? (it's already a List..)

Comment: i have to. it's does not accept return type

Comment: You probably are recursively calling the method to get a stackoverflow.  I would but a break point on 1st line of code and see if you reach the break point more than once.  Then use the Call Stack to find where the recursion is occurring.  If this doesn't work then check if any classes have properties that should be static.

Comment: Do you need `AsExpandable()` to use `PredicateBuilder`? Also, since you are ANDing, `PredicateBuilder` seems like overkill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use LINQ to create the `List` and then just use regular `IQueryable` `Where`:

```
private IQueryable<KontratMasraflari> SKontratMasraflari() {
    var _kontratlar = SKontrat().ToList();//IQueryable Method
    var _tumMasraflar = SKontrat.GroupJoin(db.KontratMasraflaris, sk => sk.ID, km => km.KontratID, (sk, kmg) => kmg.Any() ? kmg.Single() : new KontratMasraflari { KontratID = sk.ID }).ToList();

    var _result = _tumMasraflar.Where(x => x.Silindi == 0);

    if (txtFirmaTuru.Text != string.Empty)
        _result = _result.Where(x => x.FirmaTuru == txtFirmaTuru.Text);
    if (txtBelgeNo.Text != string.Empty)
        _result = _result.Where(x => x.BelgeNumarasi == txtBelgeNo.Text);
    if (txtMasraf.Text != string.Empty)
        _result = _result.Where(x => x.Masraf == txtMasraf.Text);
    if (txtGelirGider.Text != string.Empty)
        _result = _result.Where(x => x.GelirGider == txtGelirGider.Text);

    //var _return = db.KontratMasraflaris.Where(_result); 
    return _result;
}
```